# Validation not working in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.5

I installed a new Laravel 5.5 app and created a form in `test.blade.php` view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <form method="POST" action={{ route('contact') }}>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="text" name="title">
            <input type="text" name="body">
            <input type="submit"  value="click">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and created my `PageController` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Pagecontroller extends Controller
{
   public function index(Request $request){
            $this->validate($request,[
                'title' => 'required',
                'body' => 'required',
            ]);

            return View('View');
   }
}
```

and in the `web.php` add my routes:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/test',function(){
    return View('test');
});
Route::post('/contact',['uses'=>'PageController@index','as'=>'contact']);
```

My problem is when I submit the form with or without data nothing happen and the page just reload and when I remove the validation code:

```
 $this->validate($request,[
                    'title' => 'required',
                    'body' => 'required',
                ]);
```

it return the requests I can't understand what is the problem because I tested it before and it was working in Laravel 5.4. Can any one help me?

Comment: what was "working in 5.4"?

Comment: Your `index` function does essentially nothing (it's validating, but not doing anything after that), and returning the `$request` is quite odd. What *are* you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: the (validation) working and when inputs is null returns error

Comment: its just for test i have this problem in my real project and i want to know what is my mistake

Comment: Try:     `$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);` as per the 5.5 docs, although what you have looks ok

Comment: @mohsen.MY ... we dont want a test, we want the real problem .... you taking the problem you have and trying to make an example of it probably has lost the actual problem during the way, since you dont know what the problem is in the first place

Comment: not worked :( same result ..just refresh the page

Comment: What do you *exactly* expect from the failing validation?

Beside this, your `test.blade.php` refers to a `View.blade.php`.

Comment: Please add errors to your view like : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: i want to return view just when inputs insert and return error if input is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class Pagecontroller extends Controller
    {
       public function index(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
                ]);

                return View('View');
               }
            }
```

And your view code should be:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    @if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
    @endif
            <form method="POST" action={{ route('contact') }}>
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input type="text" name="title">
                <input type="text" name="body">
                <input type="submit"  value="click">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```